# My Python code TimeLimitExceeded. How do I optimize and reduce the number of operations in my code?

Tags: python, performance

Here is my code:

```
def seperateInputs(inp):
    temp = inp.split()
    n = int(temp[0])
    wires = []
    temp[1] = temp[1].replace('),(', ') (')
    storeys = temp[1][1:len(temp[1])-1].split()
    for each in storeys:
        each = each[1:len(each)-1]
        t = each.split(',')
        wires.append((int(t[0]), int(t[1])))
    return n, wires


def findCrosses(n, wires):
    cross = 0
    for i in range(len(wires)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(wires)):
            if (wires[i][0] < wires[j][0] and wires[i][1] > wires[j][1]) or (wires[i][0] > wires[j][0] and wires[i][1] < wires[j][1]):
                cross += 1
    return cross

def main():
    m = int(input())
    for i in range(m):
        inp = input()
        n, wires = seperateInputs(inp)
        print(findCrosses(n, wires))
main()
```

The question asks:
[image]

[image]

I also tested my own sample input which got me the output that is correct:

```
Sample input:
3
20 [(1,8),(10,18),(17,19),(13,16),(4,1),(8,17),(2,10),(11,0),(3,2),(12,3),(18,14),(7,7),(19,5),(0,6)]
20 [(3,4),(10,7),(6,11),(7,17),(13,9),(15,19),(19,12),(16,14),(12,8),(0,3),(8,15),(4,18),(18,6),(5,5),(9,13),(17,1),(1,0)]
20 [(15,8),(0,14),(1,4),(6,5),(3,0),(13,15),(7,10),(5,9),(19,7),(17,13),(10,3),(16,16),(14,2),(11,11),(8,18),(9,12),(4,1)]

Sample output:
38
57
54
```

However although small input worked but medium to large input gives me TimeLimitExceeded error:
[image]

How do I optimize this? Is there a way to have much less operations than what I already have? TIA.

Comment: The input after the initial number is valid Python syntax.  You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert that to a list of tuples directly.

Comment: If you sort the list, you can eliminate half the comparisons because you'll know one end is already in order.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry how do you apply that? I've never used ast.literal_eval. Could you please demonstrate? I am yet that advance in coding atm. Thanks

Comment: @TimRoberts I applied ast.literal_eval but now it gives me a list of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a handful of things you can do.

First, things are easier to compute if you sort the list first by the left building. This costs a little up-front, but makes things easier and fast as you process because you only need to compare how many lower second elements you've seen so far. The code is nice and simple for this:

```
l =  [(3,4),(10,7),(6,11),(7,17),(13,9),(15,19),(19,12),(16,14),(12,8),(0,3),(8,15),(4,18),(18,6),(5,5),(9,13),(17,1),(1,0)]

def count_crossings(l):
    s = sorted(l, key=lambda p: p[0])
    endpoints = []
    count = 0
    for i, j in s:
        count += sum(e > j for e in endpoints)
        endpoints.append(j)
    return count

count_crossings(l)
# 57
```

This is a little inefficient because you are looping through `endpoints` for every point. If you could also keep `endpoints`   sorted, you would only need to count the number less than the given right hand boiling floor. Anytime you thing of keeping a list sorted, you should consider the amazing built-in library [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). This will make things an order of magnitude faster:

```
import bisect

def count_crossings_b(l):
    s = sorted(l, key=lambda p: p[0])
    endpoints = []
    count = 0
    for i, j in s:
        bisect.insort_left(endpoints, j)
        count += len(endpoints) - bisect.bisect_right(endpoints, j) 

    return count

count_crossings_b(l)
# 57
```

The various timings on my laptop look like:

```
l = [(random.randint(1, 200), random.randint(1, 200)) for _ in range(1000)]

%timeit findCrosses(l) # original
# 179 ms ± 1.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit count_crossings(l)
# 38.1 ms ± 2.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit count_crossings_b(l)
# 1.08 ms ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: How do you put this into my code? Do you replace the findCrosses(n, wires) function? Then how about seperateInputs(inp) function do I have change it up? How do I get the input with your function? Thanks.

Comment: How do you plug your function into my code? I tried replacing my findCrosses(n, wires) function with your first part but now it just gives me error.

Comment: @JesseLingLing yes, this replaces `findCrosses`, but since you don't need `n` I didn't keep the argument: `count_crossings_b(l)` where `l` is the list of pairs: `[(1,8),(10,18),...`

Comment: I have replaced the findCrosses with your first part, but it gives me error: File "C:\Users\Jesse\A2.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    s = sorted(l, key=lambda p: p[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @JesseLingLing look at the value of `l` in the first code example. You need to turn the string given to you into a list of tuples like this. Try printing the input and see what you have. You function `seperateInputs()` produces a list where the first value is just an integer. You need to pass in the list of values without this. In your codes that might be `seperateInputs(s)[1]`

Comment: Thanks! I tried seperateInputs(s)[1] and it worked. Looks like it passed both medium and large cases. However it was the second code that worked as the first part also gave me TimeLimitExceeded error.